# Where is System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer?

Tags: .net-3.5

Gotta be getting close to a long weekend.... I'm trying to create a DispatchTimer. I found some sample code but can't run it due to a missing namespace.

I have the namespace, System.Windows.Threading, but in which assembly can I find it? I tried System, System.Windows... nada.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is in System.Windows.Threading, but you need to be sure you are referencing the WindowsBase.dll assembly as well.

Answer (score 8):

The msdn docs say it's in WindowsBase.dll . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

Comment: Me too, I think it's because it's so counter intuitive to be in an assembly with a different name.