# What is the namespace for DispatcherTimer class?

Tags: c#

Ok! This sounds like a "Let Me Google That For You", well I did and here is the MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

so in MSDN it says it is System.Windows.Threading   but my VS IDE is giving error on it.

What is going on? I want be able to use DispatcherTimer class.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a reference?

Comment: A search of StackOverflow would have given you the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954802/where-is-system-windows-threading-dispatchertimer

Comment: The correct question is "What is the **assembly** for the `DispatchTimer` class?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MSDN page also says:

> **Assembly:** WindowsBase

Did you reference this assembly? Is your project even a WPF project? (WindowsBase is a WPF library.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll`. It's a WPF assembly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you added a reference to the WindowsBase assembly?

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN page also says you need to reference WindowsBase.dll, did you that?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation also says that the class is in the WindowsBase assembly, so you need a reference to that assembly to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the WindowsBase.dll is referenced in your project. (Namespaces and their classes can exist in multiple assemblies and only a handful of assemblies are referenced in projects by default.)

Answer (score 1):

or you can use the following:

using Windows.UI.Xaml;

Documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer)